# Inject css to a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

see below `my-component.vue`.This Component needs to be themable.

It needs to get extrenal css sheet as i need to allow other developers to customize its inner look.

Is there any other approach than [accept a javascript object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1)?

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .A {
    background-color:green;
  }
  .B {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .C {
    background-color: yellow
  }
</style>
```

Comment: why this approach is not good?

Comment: i have experience with css in javascript from react. maybe it's ok, but it's not perfect and not intuitive to vue developers

Comment: Don't use scoped CSS and name the classes .component__class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your component:

```html
<template>
  <div :class="boxStyle"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      boxStyle: {
        type: String,
        default: 'box-default'
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.box-default {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
</style>
```

the user could use it that way:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <my :boxStyle="'mySpecialBox'"></my>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import myCompoentns from './components/myComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    'my': myCompoentns
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .mySpecialBox {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

That way, the user can define any style he wants, to any class name he wishes. He just need to use the appropriate property name.
The scoped styling has no side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "deep" selector to override any styles inside "scoped" component styles.

```
<style scoped>
.a >>> .b { /* ... */ }
</style>
```

Details: [vue-loader/deep-selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)